# Should Elder Sign: Omens (iPad app) be tagged differently Elder Sign (board game)?

Tags: discussion, tags

**Elder Sign** is a board game.

**Elder Sign: Omens** is an iOS app based on the board game, but [with some distinct differences](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7103/what-are-the-differences-between-elder-signs-and-elder-sign-omens).

I would argue that the differences are significant enough that the two games should not be grouped under the same tag. Seeing [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5247/what-are-some-good-strategies-for-elder-sign-omens) which has the tag [elder-sign](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elder-sign) on it, the same tag used for questions about the board game, was what originally prompted my question about the differences, since I was curious whether or not it was actually an exact copy.

It seems that it is not an exact copy, [based on the answer I've received](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/7130/2123) as well as the small amount I've played the iOS game, which I purchased after asking the question.

It also raises the question of whether or not questions about the app belong here, or on Gaming.SE.

Comment: see also: http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/34/should-questions-purely-about-online-versions-of-a-game-be-allowed

Answer (score 2):

Since Omens is a distinct game with it's own title and it's own unique rules, a game which is designed and played only on digital devices (a "video game", as it were), it does not really belong on this site.  This isn't so much a computer implementation of a physical game as it is a new game derived from the original; just because the original it is based on is on-topic does not automatically make the derived work on-topic as well.

Any questions should somehow tie back to the actual physical board-game version to be relevant to this site, at which point the existing [elder-sign](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elder-sign) is sufficient (possibly with [online](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online) or [computers](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computers) tacked on).  If the question is only applicable to Omens and not the board game itself, then it should go to [Gaming.SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/).

Creating a new tag exclusively for a video game seems needless, and goes against the core philosophy of this site.

Comment: +1 Here here. Either this computer implementation is close enough that the boardgame & computer tag are sufficient, or it isn't close enough and doesn't belong on BG.SE.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for these types of questions is just to use the [computers](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computers) tag in addition to the board game in question.

Answer (score -1):

Since this is a game with distinct rules, but based on the board game, why wouldn't we just use a different tag like [elder-sign-omens](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elder-sign-omens)? It's no different than a tag like [dominion-seaside](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dominion-seaside) which is about that particular expansion of Dominion, or [magic-online](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-online) which is about the online version of Magic the Gathering.